# How to perform Data Augmentation on Custom Generator with Siamese Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation, siamese-network

I have the following Custom Generator for building pairs of images for siamese networks, as unfortunately all my training data do not fit on my GPU's memory:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)  # for reproducibility

import random
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input, Lambda
from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class DataGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, batch_sz):
       
        print("[INFO] loading dataset...")

        trainX=np.load("features_and_labels/energy/train1-images.npy") 
        trainY=np.load("features_and_labels/energy/train1-labels.npy") 
 
        trainX, trainY = shuffle(trainX, trainY)

        trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(trainX, trainY, test_size=0.30, stratify=trainY, random_state=42)
        
        trainX = trainX / 255.0
        testX = testX / 255.0
                 
        print("READY")
            # create training+test positive and negative pairs
        digit_indices = [np.where(trainY == i)[0] for i in range(8)]
        self.tr_pairs, self.tr_y = self.create_pairs(trainX, digit_indices)
        digit_indices = [np.where(testY == i)[0] for i in range(8)]
        self.te_pairs, self.te_y = self.create_pairs(testX, digit_indices)

        self.tr_pairs_0 = self.tr_pairs[:, 0]
        self.tr_pairs_1 = self.tr_pairs[:, 1]
        self.te_pairs_0 = self.te_pairs[:, 0]
        self.te_pairs_1 = self.te_pairs[:, 1]

        self.batch_sz = batch_sz
        self.samples_per_train  = (self.tr_pairs.shape[0]/self.batch_sz)*self.batch_sz
        self.samples_per_val    = (self.te_pairs.shape[0]/self.batch_sz)*self.batch_sz
        self.cur_train_index=0
        self.cur_val_index=0
        del trainX, trainY,
        #(pairTest, labelTest) = utils.make_pairs(testX, testY)
        print("DONE")
        del testX,testY

    def create_pairs(self, x, digit_indices):
        pairs = []
        labels = []
        n = min([len(digit_indices[d]) for d in range(8)]) - 1
        for d in range(8):
            for i in range(n):
                z1, z2 = digit_indices[d][i], digit_indices[d][i+1]
                pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
                inc = random.randrange(0, 8)
                dn = (d + inc) % 7
                z1, z2 = digit_indices[d][i], digit_indices[dn][i]
                pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
                labels += [1, 0]
        return np.array(pairs), np.array(labels)

    def next_train(self):
        while 1:
            self.cur_train_index += self.batch_sz
            if self.cur_train_index >= self.samples_per_train:
                        self.cur_train_index=0
            yield ([self.tr_pairs_0[self.cur_train_index:self.cur_train_index+self.batch_sz],              self.tr_pairs_1[self.cur_train_index:self.cur_train_index+self.batch_sz]],self.tr_y[self.cur_train_index:self.cur_train_index+self.batch_sz])

    def next_val(self):
        while 1:
            self.cur_val_index += self.batch_sz
            if self.cur_val_index >= self.samples_per_val:
                self.cur_val_index=0
            yield ([self.te_pairs_0[self.cur_val_index:self.cur_val_index+self.batch_sz], self.te_pairs_1[self.cur_val_index:self.cur_val_index+self.batch_sz]],                    self.te_y[self.cur_val_index:self.cur_val_index+self.batch_sz])
```

I would like to use the following data augmentation techniques in these pairs of images:

```
 augmentator=ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")
```

However, I have the following problem when calling it, here is how I do it

```
convnet = resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3))
# Add the final fully connected layers
x = convnet.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
preds = Dense(18, activation='sigmoid')(x) # Apply sigmoid
convnet = Model(inputs=convnet.input, outputs=preds)

#Applying above model for both the left and right images
encoded_l = convnet(left_input)
encoded_r = convnet(right_input)
# Euclidian Distance between the two images or encodings through the Resnet-50 architecture
Euc_layer = Lambda(lambda tensor:K.abs(tensor[0] - tensor[1]))
# use and add the distance function
Euc_distance = Euc_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])
#identify the prediction
prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(Euc_distance)
#Define the network with the left and right inputs and the ouput prediction
siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)

#Calling the generator for me
datagen = mycustomgenerator_v2.DataGenerator(config.BATCH_SIZE)

print("[INFO] compiling model...")
   
siamese_net.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd", metrics="accuracy")
       
# train the model
print("[INFO] training model...")

lr_reducer= ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=np.sqrt(0.1), cooldown=0, patience=3, min_lr=0.5e-6)
early_stopper=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0.1, patience=250,restore_best_weights=True,verbose=1)
model_checkpoint= ModelCheckpoint("best_weight.h5", monitor="val_accuracy", save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True,mode='auto')
callbacks=[lr_reducer,early_stopper,model_checkpoint]

augmentator=ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=20,
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest")

history=siamese_net.fit(augmentator.flow(datagen.next_train()), steps_per_epoch=datagen.samples_per_train, epochs=config.EPOCHS, validation_data=datagen.next_val(), validation_steps=datagen.samples_per_val, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Then the following error returns to me

```
 File "train_siamese_network.py", line 163, in <module>
    history=siamese_net.fit(augmentator.flow(datagen.next_train()), steps_per_epoch=datagen.samples_per_train, epochs=config.EPOCHS, validation_data=datagen.next_val(), validation_steps=datagen.samples_per_val, callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 854, in flow
    return NumpyArrayIterator(
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 450, in __init__
    super(NumpyArrayIterator, self).__init__(
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/numpy_array_iterator.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.x = np.asarray(x, dtype=self.dtype)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'
```

For sure I am not calling the data augmentator on the generator correctly, I also checked other similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178837/how-to-do-keras-image-augmentation-using-custom-data-generator),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399866/triplet-siamese-and-softmax-in-tensorflow) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178837/how-to-do-keras-image-augmentation-using-custom-data-generator) but they are not helping me. Therefore, how am I supposed to call data augmentation on the custom generator for my siamese network?

Comment: All you need augmentation! Why don't you implement `ImageDataGeneratoator` functionalities in `albumentation` and use them in your custom data gen?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of doing so?

Comment: You can use `tf.image.random*` to apply random data augmentations like in `ImageDataGenerator` or write your own functions to augment.
if you need more info on `tf.image`, check [here](https://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image).

Comment: Found a solution to this problem ? I am stuck exactly at the same point

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to apply the ImageDataAugmentation in Pairs Dataset.
But I can tell you that a possibility is to generate the images in your disk. It means that you will generate images from the original Dataset (when there are no pairs), and in the next step you transform it to pairs.

As a disadventage, this method will put very similar images in Test and Train data, that could mean overfiting.

Comment: if you have a better option, please share it :D